# commitMutation prevents setState from re-rendering component in handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay

I'm trying to implement a form in Relay, which when you click the submit button, the text is replaced with a loading icon.

Handle submit function:

```
const handleSubmitNewDetails = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setIsDetailsInFlight(true); // Show loading icon
  commitUpdateDetails(
    {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      dob: dob,
  },
  () => { setIsDetailsInFlight(false) }, // on completed
  () => { setIsDetailsInFlight(false) }, // on error
);
```

};

My handleSubmit function is supposed to set the state of the mutation's "in flight" status to true. This causes rerender when commitUpdateDetails is not present, successfully rendering the loading icon. When commitupdateDetails is present, this does not work.

commitUpdateDetails works, and I added an artificial delay in response time to test the loading icon, so delay is not an issue.

I am guessing that relay or react do not finish setting the state allowing a rerender unless the handle function is completed, even when waiting for async functions? If so is there a way to get around this...?

Update:

Not using setState hooks in the callbacks makes the loading icon appear, so I guess react/relay is managing this, not sure how to make a solution.

Update 2:

Setting a simple handler using setTimeout instead of commitMutation works perfectly, so I don't get why no render occurs while waiting for the mutation's completion.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping commitMutation (called in commitUpdateDetails) in a promise works. I don't know why it doesn't work before. An explanation would be great :)